# Maven assembly plugin not producing jar-with-dependencies any more, why?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

This is in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>tahrir.TrMain</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can view the entire pom.xml [here](https://gist.github.com/635241128638aedce616).

And this is the [output](https://gist.github.com/1098711a4514f5231490) when I run "mvn -DskipTests=true assembly:assembly".

Note that it seems to be building
`tahrir/target/tahrir-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` 
but not
 `tahrir/target/tahrir-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Why isn't it building jar-with-dependencies given that this is the descriptionRef I've specified in the pom?  This was working properly before and I don't know what might have changed to break it...?

Comment: Did you "re-run Maven with the -e switch"?

Comment: Yes, but its just an elaborate explanation that it can't find the tahrir-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar file - it explains nothing about why the assembly plugin didn't produce that file :-(

Comment: And this used to work and just stopped working? (You mention "anymore" in the title.)

Comment: I made various changes, reinstalled Eclipse, frankly it would be a serious PITA to isolate what exactly changed that broke it :-/

Comment: Frankly I don't see what eclipse has to do with this unless you only build from eclipse. Do you get the same result from command line?

Comment: Eclipse almost certainly has nothing to do with it - that is the only thing I can recall changing :-/  Everything I'm talking about is from the command line after a "mvn clean"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $ mvn -DskipTests=true assembly:assembly

It looks like you are *directly* invoking the `assembly` goal of `assembly` plugin rather than use the maven lifecycle like `install` or `package`.

> [INFO] --- proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) @ tahrir ---

And the `proguard plugin` kicks in *before* the assembly is complete.  It looks for the *jar-with-dependencies* which does not exist as yet.

Edit: You can try binding your assembly plugin explicitly to the `package` phase by adding the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>tahrir.TrMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
     </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then run `mvn package` or `mvn install` skipping test as required.

Comment: Neither "mvn package" nor "mvn install" works.  Would you mind elaborating on what I need to do to modify the pom such that this works?  The entire pom.xml is linked from the question.  I'd be most grateful.

Comment: @sanity. Edit the answer with a possible solution. By the way `assembly:assembly` is deprecated in favor of `assembly:single`

Comment: +1 because `mvn assembly:single` worked for me. 
I'm still not certain why `mvn package` still doesn't, though. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

(Not a definitive answer but too long for a comment)

I noted that all my projects include the following for the assembly plugin:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Note that `executions` is sibling of `descriptorRefs`.

Try that.

Also:

```
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

It also a good practice to spec the version of the assembly plugin.

[edit/corrected: executions, not execute]

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no difference, unfortunately :-(

Comment: hmm. Worth a shot.  Note I will delete this non-answer in a bit.

Comment: Please do not delete it might help some one else +1 to convince you to not delete :)

Comment: Do you mean that "executions" is a sibling of descriptorRefs?  That is what I assumed you meant (it didn't work regardless)